# artisan call ask answer, laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan

How can I answer the questions in artisan commands?

```
     $this->call('test:command', [
        'model' => 'Payment3',
        '--fieldsFile' => 'jsonfile',
    ], function($console) {
        $console->writeln('No'); //answer an interactive question
        $console->writeln('Yes'); //answer an interactive question 2
    });
```

Comment: I think that the best practice here is to write a "non interactive" alternative to your command, in order to avoid that kind of situation. For example, on Linux, you can call `sudo apt-get install something` and it will ask for your confirmation before installing everything. The "non interactive" alternative for this command is `sudo apt-get install -y something`

Comment: You can't (unless you use some dirty hacks). And it's a bad idea to start with.